# Where to post a question about imap folder structure mismatch

Tags: support, site-recommendation

In my mail client I am using imap to connect to 2 different email servers. 1 account seems to work well, while in the other the folder structure does not match between the client and the webmail. As a consequence some folders do not get synced.

As it is only happening in one of the 2 accounts (with one imap server), I suspect a problem on the ISP side.

Where would be an appropriate place to ask experts for advice or a solution? (Note that I have already issued a request with the ISP, but it would be nice to increase the understanding)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds like an issue that might be on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - programming and software development,
> - video games or consoles,
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
> - electronic devices,
> - media players,
> - cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
> - asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation,
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Before posting there I suggest you first read and understand their help center, Meta and current questions [on IMAP](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bimap%5D+folder) to prevent asking a question that is not suited and/or already asked. When still in doubt ask a site recommendation / scope question on [Super User Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/) before proceeding.

Comment: Thank you very much. Posted my question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1829773/imap-folder-structure-not-synced-properly